# Trying to get property 'header_image' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I want to show last database data in my website page but I have this error "Trying to get property 'header_image' of non-object"(I have data in database) what is the problem?

controller:

```
public function show()
    {
        $edu = Classes::get()->first();
          return view('UI.classes.educationcourses'  ,  compact('edu'));
    }
```

blade:

```
 @foreach( $edu as  $class)
    <section id="home">
        <div id="home-slider">
            <div class="slide-item">
                <img src="{{ $class->header_image }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -
In controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $edu = Classes::all();
    return view('UI.classes.educationcourses',compact('edu'));
}
```

And in blade file:

```
@foreach( $edu as  $class)
<section id="home">
    <div id="home-slider">
        <div class="slide-item">
            @if($class->header_image)
              <img src="{{ asset('imagepath/'.$class->header_image) }}" alt="">
            @else
              <img src="{{ asset('imagepath/defaultimage.ext') }}" alt="">
            @endif
            <div class="slide-wrap">
```

Please make sure your image exists in the folder.

**Update:**

If you want a single row and the last one, then you don't need to go through with `foreach` loop in blade file.
Then you should try this:

```
public function show()
{
    $edu = Classes::latest()->first();
    return view('UI.classes.educationcourses',compact('edu'));
}
```

And in blade file:

```
<section id="home">
    <div id="home-slider">
        <div class="slide-item">
        @if($edu->header_image)
          <img src="{{ asset('imagepath/'.$edu->header_image) }}" alt="">
        @else
          <img src="{{ asset('imagepath/defaultimage.ext') }}" alt="">
        @endif
        <div class="slide-wrap">
```

Comment: It exist I think the problem is with first()

Comment: but I don't know how can I replace

Comment: Use, $edu = Classes::all();

Comment: only last one/single row?

Comment: thnx it work bu now I have new error: 'Property [image_header] does not exist on this collection instance.'

Comment: somewhere you are going through foreach loop. If you are using first() then please don't go through foreach loop. that's why you are getting a collection error.

Comment: Your column name is 'header_image' not 'image_header' please check again with the table column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last one by using the entry time in that table.

```
   $edu = Classes::where('any_condition',true)->order_by('upload_time', 'desc')->first();
```

And then in the blade, you can simply use `$edu` without any `@foreach` loop. Also, `where` clause is not necessary, just added it there for now.